Sharepoint Power Automate - Email When List Item (date) is 305 days from today
I am using a SharePoint list to track compliance with annual training requirements for individual users. I would like to set up an automation that notifies individual users via Outlook email when they are 60 days from being due to complete any of the individual training requirements again.
The list is set up thusly: each individual has a row designated by their userid and each training has its own date column.
Example:
The conditions: Today's date is 9/19/2024. User D. Parton comes due to complete CPR Training in 60 days.
The goal: D. Parton is notified via Outlook email that she is due to complete CPR Training in 60 days.
I would like for this to happen for each user on the list for each training requirement as soon as the conditions are met.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

You can try this: store training expiration date in one column in training tracker list, use recurrence power automate flow (triggers daily) to get the items where expiration date eq (today+60) days and send emails for those items.
